# perl compilation error in condition control

Tags: perl, scope

I do a perl script which print some sentence after calculation
i have a compilation error:

> Global symbol "$probWord" requires explicit package name at calculIM1.pl line 35.
>   Execution of calculIM1.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; ## PLE
use warnings;

 my $inFile = "tot1.txt";
my $outFile ="restEMI.txt";

my %hashFR = getVocab("ReglesFR1_1.txt");
my @result;
my $bloc = 50000;
my $cmp = 0;

open fileIn, "<$inFile" or die $!;

while (<fileIn>) {
chomp;
 my $flag = 0;
my $ligne = $_;
my @words = getWords($ligne);
if (my $prob = pop @words) {
$prob  =~ s/\(//g;
my $probWords = 1;

foreach my $word (@words)
  {
    my $probWord;

    if (exists $hashFR{$word})
      {
        $probWord = $hashFR{$word};
      }
    $probWords *= $probWord - $prob;
  #$probWords *= $probWord;
  }
 if ($probWord !=0){

 my $calc = $prob*log2($prob/$probWords);
  my $result = sprintf("(%.7f)", $calc);

 push @result, join(' ',@words, ($result)). "\n";

}
}

if(scalar(@result) == $bloc)
  {
   $cmp += $bloc;
  print "$cmp lignes traités\n";
  writeToResultFile($outFile,@result);
  @result = ();
 }
     }
      writeToResultFile($outFile,@result);
```

Comment: This :   if ($probWord !=0){

Comment: The problem is that the var `$probWord` is lexically scoped, and you declare it in one block and then call it in another.

Comment: Without this condition, the scrip works correctly.

Comment: Try making it global - i.e. define `$probWord` before the `while` loop.

Comment: You should use proper indentation to avoid these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 1):

`$probWord` is out of scope in your code. See code comments below.
Here is a nice post about it, you will definitely understand what is wrong with your code after reading it: http://perlmaven.com/scope-of-variables-in-perl

```
foreach my $word (@words)
{
    my $probWord; # $probWord declared here

    if (exists $hashFR{$word})
    {
        $probWord = $hashFR{$word};
    }
    $probWords *= $probWord - $prob;
  #$probWords *= $probWord;
    # $probWord is still "visible"

} # -> $probWord is not visible here anymore

if ($probWord !=0){ # and you are trying to use it here...

    my $calc = $prob*log2($prob/$probWords);
    my $result = sprintf("(%.7f)", $calc);

    push @result, join(' ',@words, ($result)). "\n";

}
```

Also as a note: Fix your indentation, your code is hard to read & maintain. You will experience lots of errors like this if you do not indent properly because you will be getting lost in your own code.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this line:

```
if ($probWord !=0){
```

should be:

```
if ($probWords !=0){
//       ____^
```

Comment: Thought about giving such an answer to OP, but it's better to understand why the error actually happened IMO, not how to just fix it so it disappears. This is one of the most common errors in perl and OP doesn't seem to have much experience in perl posting such a question here and judging by indentation...